# carregar valor no formulario front vazio sem iniciar com 0 [java] Thymeleaf + spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

[image: carregar imagem sem valor 0]

minha entity esta como integer e carrega n o front com valor 0, acho que seja uma coisa simples mais não compreendo muito.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver é só inicializar a entity com o valor null, assim nada será exibido. Simples assim.

```
// Inicializa integer com valor igual a null.
Integer entity = null;
```

Comment: desculpa mais o meu n aceita da erro.                                                   @NotNull  //Quebra linha//
@Column(name = "quantidade_vagas")   //Quebra linha//
private int quantidadeVagas ;

Comment: Ahh, você colocou o @NotNull, aí não vai aceitar mesmo. Coloca o código na pergunta pra facilitar as respostas.

Comment: Mas assim, pra aparecer vazio só tem duas formas: Tira o @NotNull e adiciona o required nos campos pra fazer a validação no JSF ou transforma os campos em String e atribui a string vazia pra eles.

Comment: okay,   obrigado  .